# How to specify custom SoapAction without service interface exposed

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, soap

I was wondering if it is possible to have a soap action not expose the interface

I define the service interface like this

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "/")]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "Heartbeat", Name = "Heartbeat")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/Heartbeat")]
    HeartbeatResponse Heartbeat(HeartbeatRequest request);
}
```

Implementation:

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any, Namespace = "/")]
public class Service : IService
{
    public HeartbeatResponse Heartbeat(HeartbeatRequest request)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<behavior name="EndpointBehavior">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
</behavior>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SOAP12">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<service behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehavior" name="xxxxxx.Service">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SOAP12" name="Service" bindingNamespace="/" contract="xxxxxx.IService" />
</service>
```

Here is the response I get:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">/IService/HeartbeatResponse</a:Action>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <heartbeatResponse xmlns="urn://Ocpp/Cs/2012/06/">
         <currentTime>2013-08-07T19:59:38.5842774Z</currentTime>
      </heartbeatResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I would like "/HeartbeatResponse" or "HeartbeatResponse"

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">/HeartbeatResponse</a:Action>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <heartbeatResponse xmlns="urn://Ocpp/Cs/2012/06/">
         <currentTime>2013-08-07T19:35:57.9349568Z</currentTime>
      </heartbeatResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Set the ReplyAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.replyaction.aspx):

```
[OperationContract(ReplyAction="http://Microsoft.WCF.Documentation/ResponseToOCAMethod")]
string SampleMethod(string msg);
```